# wamp server error

Tags: wampserver

I downloaded wamp server, then went to the phpMyAdmin panel and messed around with the privileges of my
database, and I gave a new password and username, and now I am getting this message
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I cannot acces my server anymore.
...I tried to reinstall the wamp server and I even did a system reset for a previous date
but nothing helped.
I tried to find the configuration php in the myadmin library but no luck.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Set your mysql server to use a blank password like this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Your mysql server should be somewhere in your wampserver directory. I hope you can use a command prompt

Answer (score 0):

By default wamp installs with the mysql username root and no password. If you setup a new username/password you need to update your config file. The config file for phpMyAdmin, named config.inc.php, default location is C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1 (depending on what version of phpmyadmin comes with the wampserver you got).